# Avoiding the Sydney, Nova Scotia error

Tags: bookings, tips-and-tricks, terminology

A Dutch student has [flown](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-39459471) to Sydney, Nova Scotia, a town with a population of 32,000, instead of the one in Australia, population five million. It's [not the first time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sydney,_Nova_Scotia#Airport) it's happened.

There are several other pairs of cities with similar or identical names (e.g., Manchesters in New Hampshire and the UK; San Joses in California and Costa Rica). What's the best way of avoiding this problem when booking international flights?

Comment: Other famous examples: London (Ontario, Canada) vs London (UK); Birmingham (Alabama, US) vs Birmingham (UK); Manchester (NH, US) vs Manchester (UK); Rochester (NY, US) vs Rochester (MN, US); San Jose (CA, US) vs San Jose (Costa Rica); Florence (SC, US) vs Florence (Italy).  One good solution is to become familiar with airport codes.

Comment: Step 1: don't be an idiot

Comment: Step 2: see step 1

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56447/discussion-on-question-by-andrew-grimm-avoiding-the-sydney-nova-scotia-error).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Check the airport code**.  City names may be similar, but they always have unique [three-letter airport codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Air_Transport_Association_airport_code), and these are always shown in flight booking engines.  So just look them up on Wikipedia, and you won't mistake [`YQY`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sydney/J.A._Douglas_McCurdy_Airport) with [`SYD`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sydney_Airport).

Comment: Also a good way of checking you're going to, eg, the "real" Frankfurt Airport (`FRA`) and not Frankfurt-Hahn (`HHN`), 75 miles away...

Comment: But how to know you've got the right airport code?  I'm going to San José; is it SJC or SJO?

Comment: @phoog do you know the *way* to San José?

Comment: Many booking sites (and certainly Wikipedia) do maps with the information. So double check on a site that has both a map and an airport code.

Comment: Alternatively, you might enter the three-letter airport code on a flighttracker, e.g. flightradar24.com will show the airport on a map.

Comment: @RobertColumbia I've been away so long I may go wrong and lose my way.

Comment: Problem -- IATA airport codes actually are *not* guaranteed to be unique, best I can tell at least...

Comment: @UnrecognizedFallingObject: IATA describes the airport (or rather, location) codes as [a unique three-letter code](http://www.iata.org/services/Pages/codes.aspx). Do you have any evidence to the contrary; any example of two locations with the same IATA location code, or similar?

Comment: Airport codes aren't 100% unique, because there are multiple conflicting authorities. For example, "QSF" is the metropolitan-area airport code generically denoting all airports in California's San Francisco Bay Area, but it's *also* the specific airport code for some airport in Algeria.

Comment: @ruakh There is only one authority for _IATA_ codes: IATA. These are the ones that are used on airline tickets. QSF is only the IATA code for Setif, Algeria. Perhaps QSF is the FAA's identifier for the Bay Area? It doesn't seem to be IATA's.

Comment: @ruakh There are indeed some conflicting IATA and US FAA codes, although these are generally very small airports without scheduled flights. QSF is neither though, it's a booking engine only metropolitan area code covering multiple airports (SFO, OAK, SJC) and it will never appear on a ticket.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: I don't know why you think that's helpful. In my experience, an airport code's issuing authority is *never* written on a ticket/itinerary/etc.; and if I were to end up in the wrong place, it would be cold comfort to say that it's someone else's fault for using a non-IATA code.

Comment: @jpakotal: Yeah, I know; my point was just that airport codes aren't a utopia of non-ambiguity, either, at least unless you have a better understanding of them than most people do (or than this answer provides). It's an important cross-check against the airport name, but you can't just use airport codes exclusively, ignore the names, and assume that all will be well.

Comment: @ruakh My claim is that the ticket will use IATA codes. If your ticket says QSF, it means "Setif, Algeria", not "Whatever airport in the Bay Area the pilot feels like flying to, today."

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Fair enough, but this answer mentions "flight booking engines" rather than "tickets". My point is simply that there are some subtleties with airport codes, and while they're certainly helpful, you can't just ignore airport names and assume that airport codes' supposed uniqueness will always carry the day (unless you know more about airport codes than what this answer tries to teach you).

Answer (score 6):

Mainly, you avoid these types of mistakes by just double checking the IATA codes (as mentioned by the other answers) for your destination airport... when you're paying to fly across the world, it pays to be extra careful, and make sure you've done your homework.

- **Check the IATA airport codes** -  kind of an obvious one. Research exactly where it is you're landing. Google map it, the whole deal. I really like [airportcod.es](http://airportcod.es/) for this, and [WikiVoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Sydney_Airport) which tells you about the airport, which airlines serve it, and how to get to it via different forms of transport. This is especially important when using low-cost carriers (Ryanair I'm looking at you...) because they take some "creative liberties" with the airport names. Ex: "Milan Bergamo Airport" (is not in Milan! But 1.5 hours away in the small city of Bergamo.)

Additionally though:

- **Check the total flight time** - I'm surprised no one's mentioned this. If I was flying from Europe to Australia and noticed the flight time was less than 12 hours, that should raise some red flags. I like to use Google Flights to get an idea of the flights times, and usual number of layovers for any particular itinerary, *before even trying to buy the fare.*

Comment: Interesting you mention flight time - one reason that the Dutch student chose this flight was because it was about $200 cheaper than the alternatives, for reasons that are all too obvious in hindsight.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to avoid this problem is to use a travel agent, who will be familiar with the airport codes. Of course, most people prefer to avoid the inconvenience and expense by buying the ticket ourselves, which puts the responsibility for checking the details on our own shoulders.

Comment: Based on my experience with travel agents, I consider i far more likely that a travel agent makes such a mistake, than that I do.

Comment: @gerrit: even if you are right, you can then tell the agent to sort out the mistake. and pay any fees.

Comment: Based on my experience with travel agents, they will purposely book a flight to Sydney, Nova Scotia so they get kickbacks from the city's tourism industry.